# Do all non Muslims go to jahanum?

Tags: non-muslim, imaan

My question is a bit long.......if  anyone dies with disbelief to Islam which have not received TRUE message of Islam or one had MISCONCEPTION about Islam and that denied him from path for example act of terrorism by those who call themselves muslims or children which they don't know and don't have the dependence in belief or those Muslims who killed non Muslims without a valid reason, or those people who didn't have the time think of it being busy to arrange at least arrange one time meal to not die as starvation...  sometimes I think of Allah swt sent prophet ..  in the time of prophet saw the prophet was there. people could see his nature,miracles and so on and believed him easily.........my question is if people mentioned above  die as non-believers so what will be there fate in hereafter what will be Allah swt's judgement,so how he would deal with them,still they are puted in hellfire?

Answer (score 0):

Won't go to Jahannam if the following conditions matches:

1. If he never heard of Islam with details
2. If he is Muttaki(Afraid of ALlah)
3. If he didn't Shirk anyone with Allah(he might call Allah anything eg. God, Ishwar, Pravu, Creator)
4. If Allah forgives him

Allah also said that,

> Those who believe in the Oneness of Allah and fear Allah much, and love Allah much], no fear shall come upon them nor shall they grieve.’ [Qur'an 10:62]

Answer (score -1):

Allah always gave his sign to his servants. For one who believe in media, they shouldn't believe just like that without researching first whether something is indeed true or false.